# IndexPath.row wrong value with multiple sections

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have sections and different arrays for each section. It works great and show the right Object. But when I set the tag form an UIBUtton, the indexPath.row passed as button.tag is returning 1 instead 0 in second session..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionsTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *secAtt = [attractions objectForKey:sectionTitle];

Evento *evento = (Evento*)[secAtt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if(evento.listaImagens && [evento.listaImagens count] > 0) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellSemFoto" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
 UIButton *btnCompartilhar = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:40];
    [btnCompartilhar.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
    btnCompartilhar.titleLabel.text = sectionTitle;
    btnCompartilhar.tag = indexPath.row;
    [btnCompartilhar addTarget:self action:@selector(compartilharClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  return cell;
 }
```

and here I get the indexPath

```
  UIButton *botaoCompartilhar = (UIButton *)sender;
   int index = botaoComapartilhar.tag;
```

index is returning 1 in the first row from second section

**EDIT** I discovered that indexpath.row is correct but not setting the botaoCompartilhar.tag.

I discovered it with the following code:

```
 UIButton *btnCompartilhar = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:40];
[btnCompartilhar.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
btnCompartilhar.titleLabel.text = sectionTitle;
btnCompartilhar.tag = indexPath.row;
[btnCompartilhar addTarget:self action:@selector(compartilharClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
NSLog(@"%@ %i %i", evento.entretenimento.nome, btnCompartilhar.tag, indexPath.row);
```

Comment: What would be the index for?

Comment: For example. The second row from second section is returning 0 instead 1...would be 1...Sometimes the index is wrong...0 instead 1. 1 instead 0..1 instead 2...Only the first section always works correctly

Comment: I meant what should that `int index` variable will be used for?

Comment: the variable index is used to know which element from array should be taken when the user click in share button

Answer (score 0):

Two observations:

1. You have two sections, then if you put the tag as `indexPath.row` then in the selector you'll have two buttons with tag 1, two for tag 2, and so on.
2. I like better using the Control `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` rather than `UIControlEventTouchDown`.

So to sum up, try to do:

```
btnCompartilhar.tag = indexPath.section*1000 + indexPath.row;
```

Instead of:

```
btnCompartilhar.tag = indexPath.row;
```

So you get a unique tag value for all buttons. And then you'll need to manage the index making something like:

```
NSInteger indexSection = (button.tag)/1000;
NSInteger indexRow = (button.tag)%1000;

if (indexSection == 0){
    //first section
    //go get the element on index indexRow of the first section array
} else {
    //second section
    //go get the element on index indexRow of the second section array
}
```

Comment: the problem isn't the indexPath.row. I did debug and discovered that viewWithTag for my btnCompartilhar is only working once. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I use viewWithTag and change the Button's tag to the indexPath.row...Then the next time, there's not viewWithTag 40.

My solution was

```
  UIButton *btnCompartilhar = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:40];
[btnCompartilhar.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
btnCompartilhar.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i|%@",indexPath.row, sectionTitle]; 
[btnCompartilhar addTarget:self action:@selector(compartilharClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and to get the indexPath.row and the sectionTitle:

```
int tag = 0;
NSString *titleLabel = botaoCompartilhar.titleLabel.text;

NSRange range = [botaoCompartilhar.titleLabel.text rangeOfString:@"|"];
if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
    NSString *tagStr = [botaoCompartilhar.titleLabel.text substringToIndex:range.location];
    tag = [tagStr intValue];
    if([botaoCompartilhar.titleLabel.text length] > range.location+1)
        titleLabel = [botaoCompartilhar.titleLabel.text substringFromIndex:range.location+1];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661490/viewwithtag-returning-nil-return-the-object-only-once#new-answer