# ViewWIthTag returning nil (return the object only once)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the cells with identifiers in Storyboard and the respective objects with tags. The first time that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, viewWIthTag returns the object ok. The next times the btnCompartilhar, for example, is nil.

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    NSString *sectionTitle = [sectionsTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *secAtt = [attractions objectForKey:sectionTitle];

    Evento *evento = (Evento*)[secAtt objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if(evento.listaImagens && [evento.listaImagens count] > 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellSemFoto" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];



    UIButton *btnCompartilhar = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:40];
    [btnCompartilhar.titleLabel setHidden:YES];
    btnCompartilhar.titleLabel.text = sectionTitle;
    btnCompartilhar.tag = indexPath.row;
    [btnCompartilhar addTarget:self action:@selector(compartilharClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    return cell;
}
```

I executed the command po [cell.contentView recursiveDescription] and discovered that the Button with tag 40 is there only at the first time. But all the others objects are all the times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `btnCompartilhar.tag = indexPath.row;` changes the tag, so you can't find it again next time when the cell is reused.

You should not rely on `viewWithTag:`, instead you should create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass and add properties which allow you to access all of the views you need. The cell can also then have additional information like the row number if you need it.

Note that your current approach has other issues, like adding the target and action multiple times, which is also not a great idea.